# How to align text in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to align text like :

[image]

but mine display like :

[image]

CSS code :

```
  .caption > p
   {
       color: black;
       width: 100%;
       margin-top: 0px;
       text-align: center;
   }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"> 
          <div class="caption">
           <h3>Preventive Maintenance</h3>
              <p>
                  As a team starts to schedule preventive maintenance they need a reliable 
work calendar. CMMS systems are especially good at scheduling recurring work and sending 
reminders to the right people. Organized scheduling helps even out the workload for a 
maintenance team making sure that tasks do not get forgotten
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried `float: left, and float: right` but it does not work, is there any trick to settle this issue?

Comment: Google for "css justify text". What were you imagining "`text-align: center" did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text-align: justify;` instead of `text-align: center;`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#Values for more options